# how to make api call to amazon elastic transcoder pipeline in java?

Tags: java, rest, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am not able to figure out how to make api calls to amazon elastic transcoder pipeline in java.What should be the base url for the service call or should i make the pipelines manually using the console and create jobs through my code.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-pipeline.html , still unable to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the [API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/api-reference.html) docs and create your own client using any HTTP library, but ideally, you would [use the Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elastictranscoder/AmazonElasticTranscoderClient.html) for `AmazonElasticTranscoderClient`, not create your own REST clients.

Specifically, you would want the `createPipeline(CreatePipelineRequest request)` method

The endpoints for all AWS services are listed [on a single page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#elastictranscoder_region)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, highly appreciable. Can I find an example or snippet somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there are links to example Java code in the API reference page

Comment: https://elastictranscoder.elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/2012-09-25/pipelines . This is the base url I am hitting upon but no response

Comment: First, I have never used this service. Second, I doubt putting twice  `elastictranscoder.elastictranscoder` is correct. Somehow, you need to reference your actual account info, too